# Interpretation and combinatoric

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Situation**: Imagine that we are playing a game, like Free cell. There are $52$ cards. There are eight columns, where the first four have seven cards each and the rest columns have six cards each.

**Problem**: What is the probability that there are four aces in the same column?

**My Answer**: I know the result, but I just want to know if my "interpretation" is correct. The doubt occurs when I try to explain each sides.

The four columns to left, there are $\binom{4}{1}\cdot \binom{7}{4}\cdot 4!\cdot (52-4)!$ favourable outcomes. The four colums to right, there are $\binom{4}{1}\cdot \binom{6}{4}\cdot 4!\cdot (52-4)!$ favourable outcomes. Altogether, there are $$\left [ \binom{7}{4}+\binom{6}{4} \right ]\binom{4}{1}\cdot 4!\cdot (52-4)!$$ favourable outcomes such that the four aces are in the same column. There are $52!$ possible outcomes. Hence the probability is 
$$\frac{\left [ \binom{7}{4}+\binom{6}{4} \right ]\binom{4}{1}\cdot 4!\cdot (52-4)!}{52!}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\left [ \binom{7}{4}+\binom{6}{4} \right ]\binom{4}{1}\cdot 4!\cdot (52-4)!}{52!}$$

This counts ways to :

- Select 4 places within a column of either 7 or 6 cards.
- Also selecting which of the four columns of either type.
- Arrange the aces within those places.
- Arrange the remaining cards in the remaining places.
- Divide by all ways to arrange all 52 cards.

That is entirely correct.

---

Another interpretation is: we're only interested in ways to select *places* for the aces.

There are $\binom{52}{4}$ ways to select any 4 places.   And, as you've found, there are $\binom{4}{1}\left[\binom{7}{4}+\binom{6}{4}\right]$ ways to select a column and four places within that column.   That gives:

$$\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\left[\binom{7}{4}+\binom{6}{4}\right]}{\binom{52}{4}}$$

Then when you expand the binomial in the denominator, you'll obtain the same result.